# Ĉu oni povas plani renkonti iun?

Tags: verbs

Instruisto diris al mi ke:

- "**renkonti iun**" estas hazarde
- "**renkontiĝi kun iu**" estas planita

Ĉu tio estas vera?

Pri okazo dum kiu pluraj personoj iras al la sama loko kun celo interagi kun unu la alia, mi ĉiam uzis la vorton "renkontiĝo". Mi supozas ke "renkonto" povus temi pri okazo de personoj kiuj neplanite estas en la sama loko je la sama tempo.

Kiam temas pri la verboj, mi havis la impreson ke "renkonti" estas uzata kiam ajn estas objekto, kaj renkontiĝi kiam ne estas, sendepende de ĉu estis plano aŭ ne.

- Kiom ofte la klubanoj renkontiĝas?
- Kiam vi laste renkontis vian avinon?
- Ni renkontiĝu baldaŭ por diskuti la estontecon de la projekto.
- Morgaŭ mi renkontos miajn amikojn ĉe kafejo.

Ĉu mi malpravas? Laŭ la instruisto la dua kaj kvara frazo estu:

- Kiam vi laste renkontiĝis kun via avino?
- Morgaŭ mi renkontiĝos kun miaj amikoj ĉe kafejo.

Answer (score 5):

Mi kontrolis la 77 atestojn de *renkontis* kaj la 22 atestojn de *renkontiĝis* en la Zamenhofaj tekstoj en la [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/).

Ŝajnas al mi, ke via instruisto duone pravas, almenaŭ rilate la (modelan) Z-an lingvouzon.

1. La verbo *renkonti* esprimas ĉiam neplanitan trovadon/kontraŭvenadon: *Jes, li renkontis ilin en la vojo, kiam li matene venis.*
2. Por esprimi planitan renkonton, oni uzas la verbon *renkontiĝi*: *Laŭ interkonsento Kristino renkontiĝis kun sia patro en la vilaĝo Funder*
3. Tamen *renkontiĝi* povas same bone esprimi ankaŭ hazardan interrenkonton: *Ili rapide forlasis la arbaron, trapasis la erikejon kaj denove senvojan arbaron, kaj vespere ili renkontiĝis kun rabistoj.*

Zamenhof certe inspiriĝis de la pola (mi ne kompetentas pri la rusa), kie la transitiva *spotkać kogoś* ("renkonti iun") estas uzata por hazarda kunveno, dum refleksiva *spotkać się z kimś* ("renkontiĝi kun iu") servas kutime por interkonsentitaj rendevuoj.

Answer (score 2):

`renkontiĝi kun iu` originas ofte de `renkonti sin` - **refleksiva** formo kiu inkluzivas la kun-objekto. Kaj *inter si* la renkonto probable estas planita.

Notu ke `renkonti` estas reciproka nocio: `A renkontas B` <=> `B renkontas A`.

(Mi esperas ke tio ĉi ne estas konsiderata tro granda lingvistika stultaĵo.)

Comment: Mi pensas, ke la vorto estu [*simetria*](http://vortaro.net/#simetria%20rilato) (almenaŭ en matematikaj terminoj, al kio ‘bijekcia’ apartenas).

Comment: @Joffysloffy jes, mi pensis pri matematiko; _simetria_ estis kion mi volis esprimi. Tamen nun korektis al _reciproka_ - pli bona lingvaĵo.

Comment: Mi konsentas; *reciproka* estas pli klara.